# How to display pagination link as button on gridvew asp.net?

Tags: css, asp.net, bootstrap-4, gridview

I work on asp.net web forms . I face issue I can't display pagination link as button with gray back ground on grid view control.

I need to assign CSS class to pager style on grid view to display link as button gray as exist on image below

```
  <asp:GridView ID="GridViewSearchData" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="ID"   AllowPaging="true" OnPageIndexChanging="grdData_PageIndexChanging" PageSize="10" >
                               
                                 
                               
 <PagerStyle CssClass=""/>
</asp:GridView>
```

on CSS class I need to assign class CSS to pager style on CssClass display link as button .
if you can help me with another way without CSS I accept it .

```
   <style type="text/css">
   // what I write here 

    </style
```

Expected result

[image: display as buttons]

**Updated Answer**

ok I apply first script square box page number but I need to increase

height and width of box page number surrounded page number 1,2,3 etc.

also if possible can I add background color of page number to be as in image
I apply changes as you tell me but button not same size and not same background
so How to modify CSS to do that

[image: issue on size of button page]

Answer (score 0):

There are boatloads of pager examples.

but, drop in this style sheet:

```
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        font-family: Arial;
        font-size: 10pt;
    }

    .GridPager a, .GridPager span {
        display: block;
        height: 20px;
        width: 18px;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    .GridPager a {
        background-color: #f5f5f5;
        color: #969696;
        border: 1px solid #969696;
    }

    .GridPager span {
        background-color: #A1DCF2;
        color: #000;
        border: 1px solid #3AC0F2;
    }
</style>
```

And now set class for pager:

```
<PagerStyle CssClass="GridPager" />
```

And now we see/get this:

[image]

Or how about some cute roundy ones like this:

[image]

So, this:

```
<style>
    .GridPager2 body {
        font-family: Arial;
        font-size: 10pt;
    }

    .GridPager2 a, .GridPager2 span {
        display: block;
        height: 22px;
        width: 28px;
        text-align: center;
        margin-right: 12px;
        box-shadow: 4px 4px 4px 0px gray;
        border-radius: 10px;
    }

    .GridPager2 a {
        background-color: #ddd5d5;
        border: 1px solid #969696;
        margin-right: 12px;
        box-shadow: 4px 4px 4px 0px gray;
        border-radius: 10px;
    }

        .GridPager2` a:hover {
            background-color: #789eca;
            transition: 0.5s;
        }

    .GridPager2 span {
        background-color: #808080;
        color: #000;
        border: 1px solid #3AC0F2;
    }

</style>
```

Comment: ok I apply first script square box page number but i need to increase height and width of box page number 1,2,3 etc.

Comment: can you check updated answer

Comment: so can i increase every page number box more heigh and width